# Can't render array elements from mongodb document with express-edge templating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm following this blog tutorial to learn nodejs backend along with mongodb, it seems a bit outdated(I've had to tweak some stuff to make it work) but also I'm not following it 100%, as I'm making my own front end instead of using a theme and I'm using my own database, which brings to the problem:

While rendering the post lists I want to render inside each post the list of it's tags, which in my database is an array of strings, but it doesnt work. When I try to access the first element of the array only, it return undefined.

This code doesnt render any `<li>`:

```
<div class="row" id="lista-posts">
        @each(post in posts)
            <div class="col-12">
                <a href="/posts/{{post._id}}"></a>
                <h4>{{post.titulo}}</h4>
                <ul>
                    @each(tag in post.tags)
                        <li>{{tag}}</li>
                    @endeach
                </ul>
                <div class="post-conteudo">
                    {{post.conteudo}}
                </div>
            </div>
        @endeach
    </div>
```

This one here render one `<li>` (as expected) but it's written Undefined:

```
(...)                
                <h4>{{post.titulo}}</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>{{post.tags[0]}}</li>
                </ul>
```

All the other elements like "titulo" and "conteudo" are rendered fine. For context, every post in my db has:

_id: IdObject

titulo: String

tags: Array of Strings

conteudo: String

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's because I didn't set up the `tags` array in my mongoose Schema.